# Disable a Vaadin Binding

Tags: vaadin8

I have a component (e.g. a TextField) that will be shown depending on some other selection, a radio button for example, and when it is hidden I don't want the bind on this field to be applied, so

In some place:

```
Binder binder = new Binder<SomeDTO>(SomeDTO.class);
TextField conditionalComponet = TextField("A conditional component: ");
binder.bind(conditionalComponet, "propertyX");
```

and in some other place:

```
SomeDTO someDTO = new SomeDTO;
binder.writeBean(someDTO); //Here propertyX shouldn't be filled, i.e. bind should 
                       //not be applied, to propertyX of SomeDTO if the 
                       //conditionalComponet is hidden.
```

I wouldn't like to remove the component from layout since putting it in the same position will be a problem. I tried to `setVisible(false)`, `setEnabled(false)` and `setReadOnly(true)`, but none prevent the binding to be applied. Is there a simple way of doing that?

I am using Vaadin 8.

Comment: Showing some code, a [sscce](http://sscce.org) if possible, would greatly increase the chances of us understanding what you mean by `I don't want the bind on this field to be applied` and getting an answer..

Comment: @Morfic I am not sure if I understand correctly, binding is a concept and implementation from the framework, I am unsure which code would make my statement clear. Please tell me if my edit cade my question clear or not :)

Comment: I don't even see any way to remove the whole binder once it was created. That's strange.

Comment: Not sure how your code works,  is `binder.write(someDTO);` supposed to  `binder.writeBean(someDTO);`?  Is is possible to just clear the value for propertyX in SomeDTO when the radio field changes accordingly?

Comment: If possible can youto your question, the class fields & ui components (like the radio box) in order to assist in your hide/show request.

Comment: @petey Yes, it is binder.writeBean, I will fix in the question. Your workaround might work for some situation, but not in my case. The hide and show mechanics is working fine, my problem is with the bindings. I actually have two components binding to the same property, but only one of them is shown at a time, and the binding of one is interfering with the other. I made an workaround with groovy, but I still want to know if there is something I could use on Vaadin.

Comment: @VitorCruz, I dont have a better workaround at the moment, I'd need  you update to your question with the missing pieces of your DTO and ui components

Comment: @petey I am not really looking for a workaround, but a legit way of disable a binding since I could not find one in the docs or googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no *direct* way to prevent a value from being set to a field by the binder, once it's bound. Nonetheless, you can work around this *limitation*(?!) easily, by using the **bind(HasValue<FIELDVALUE> field, [ValueProvider<BEAN,FIELDVALUE> getter](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.7/com/vaadin/server/Setter.html), [Setter<BEAN,FIELDVALUE> setter](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.7/com/vaadin/server/Setter.html))** method variant.

For a sample you can check the code below. Please note that it has just the basics parts to show the effect, so it does not have all the bells-and-whistles such as disabling or resetting the employment-date field with the check-box:

```java
import com.vaadin.data.Binder;
import com.vaadin.data.ValidationException;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class DisableBindingForField extends VerticalLayout {
    private final Person person = new Person("Dark Vaper");
    private final TextField name = new TextField("Name:");
    private final CheckBox isEmployed = new CheckBox("Is employed:");
    private final DateField dateOfEmployment = new DateField("Date of employment:");
    private final Binder<Person> binder = new Binder<>(Person.class);
    private final Button button = new Button("Save");

    public DisableBindingForField() {
        // manually bind the custom field separately (https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html - scroll to the end)
        binder.bind(dateOfEmployment, person -> person.dateOfEmployment, (person, dateOfEmployment) ->
                // if the check-box is checked then populate the pojo with the value, otherwise reset the pojo value to null
                person.setDateOfEmployment((isEmployed.getValue()) ? dateOfEmployment : null)
        );

        // automatically bind the rest of the fields
        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);

        // initial reading of the bean
        binder.readBean(person);

        // add components to the user interface
        addComponents(name, isEmployed, dateOfEmployment, button);

        // simulate a "save button"
        button.addClickListener(event -> {
            try {
                binder.writeBean(person);
                Notification.show(person.toString());
            } catch (ValidationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    // basic pojo for binding
    public class Person implements Serializable {

        private String name;
        private Boolean isEmployed;
        private LocalDate dateOfEmployment;

        public Person(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public boolean isEmployed() {
            return isEmployed;
        }

        public void setEmployed(boolean employed) {
            isEmployed = employed;
        }

        public LocalDate getDateOfEmployment() {
            return dateOfEmployment;
        }

        public void setDateOfEmployment(LocalDate dateOfEmployment) {
            this.dateOfEmployment = dateOfEmployment;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", isEmployed=" + isEmployed +
                    ", dateOfEmployment=" + dateOfEmployment +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: ignore employment date binding if check-box is not checked]

**P.S.:** Alternative *fluent-builder* style:

```java
binder.forField(dateOfEmployment)
      .bind(person -> person.dateOfEmployment, (person, dateOfEmployment) ->
          // if the check-box is checked then populate the pojo with the value, otherwise reset the pojo value to null
          person.setDateOfEmployment((isEmployed.getValue()) ? dateOfEmployment : null)
      );
```

Comment: `person.setDateOfEmployment((isEmployed.getValue()) ? dateOfEmployment : null)` still changes the value to null, but I understand, I could do `if(isEmployed.getValue() != null) {person.setDateOfEmployment(dateOfEmployment)}`.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @VitorCruz No problem. It's intentionally set to `null` because you said you wanted to clear the value. But you can extract the if outside the setter and only call it if the the check-box is checked

Answer (score 4):

@Morfic answer is no longer correct. Vaadin 8 now supports unbinding a field:

```
TextField usernameField;

binder.forField(this.usernameField)
    .bind(User::getUsername, User::setUsername);

binder.removeBinding(this.usernameField);
```